# Issue with absolute position inside relative position

Tags: css

I have a problem trying to make a flexible absolutely positioned element inside relative positioned element. Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cxHNN/

The above code works fine when the `.content` div inside the `.active` div has the largest height value. (`inner-3` in this case)

But if the `.active` class is set on any other `inner` element (with less text), the content from largest element (`inner-3`) overflows ([see example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cxHNN/1/)).

I can work this out using JavaScript, but I would like a pure css solution to this problem, such that all the `inner` elements are of equal heights without giving a fixed-height so that their height dynamically changes as the container-width changes (in a responsive layout).

**Note:**
Nevermind the pixel-based margins/widths. I had to tweak the css a little to make it work jsFiddle. They're all in % or ems in my original stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding all `.inner` divs, and only show the active div?

```
.inner .content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    margin-top: -4em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: none;}
.inner.active .content{
    display: block;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** If you need the inner divs to be the same size, you can't position them absolutely, or float them, or display them hidden or inline. So, I've done thie following:

- The flex container is positioned relative, and given enough padding that the elements inside it can be positioned top left, and position correctly. I have also set the font size 0 and prevented wrapping.
- The inner div is displayed inline-block, with a width of 0
- The active inner block is given a 100% width, so that it is the only one shown
- The H1s are positioned absolutely, and placed where you want them

http://jsfiddle.net/cxHNN/4/

You will need to play with the padding and spacing and stuff. Oh, and I only tested this on FireFox - there may be issues with other browsers.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need all the `inner` elements to be of equal heights

Comment: In that case, you have to position all the inner divs as static or relative, to make sure they all contribute to the size. Maybe use `display: inline-block`, `visibility:hidden` and `width: 0px` together (obviously using `visibility: visible` and `width: auto` for the active div)?

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working out. Can you give it a try here: http://jsfiddle.net/cxHNN/1/